# How to send MIDI or OSC signals to a Mac application from my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, midi, osc

I'm thinking of writing an iPhone/iPad application to emulate a MIDI controller. I know there are already quite a few available but I still want to do my own. I have several questions about that:

- I know a little bit about MIDI, but I've recently heard about OSC. Obviously MIDI is supported by almost all DJ software applications, but does OSC have a critical advantage that makes it compelling?
- For example, is it possible for my iOS application to send OSC messages directly to the DJ application without going through a hosted proxy application (like most remoting applications)? Is it possible with MIDI?
- If I'm forced to go through a server application installed on the host machine, I've read about Bonjour and TCP sockets to communicate between iOS and my host proxy, but how can my host proxy send MIDI or OSC signals to DJ applications? Does it have to pose as a virtual MIDI device? Are there libraries available for that? On MacOSX? On Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [vvopensource](http://code.google.com/p/vvopensource/) project on Google Code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly the kind of things I was looking for