# Publishing a MIDI source as a Bonjour service

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, midi, bonjour

I have written a VST/AU/RTAS synthesiser plugin for OSX and Windows that also has an iPhone equivalent. I would like to allow the two to communicate with each other over a local area network so that the iPhone app can be used to send MIDI controller data to the plugin. I plan to create a MIDI source on the iPhone and publish it as a Bonjour service so that the plugin running on OSX or Windows can find it and receive midi from it.

I have a couple of questions to ask about this:

1) Do I actually have to publish the MIDI source as a Bonjour service or does a coremidi host (running on iPhone) automatically publish itself?

2) Are there any code examples available that show how to do this sort of thing?

I have seen the following post but the answer to this only covers the client side, finding a Bonjour service but not the publishing side, and it transmits MIDI via OSC, and it only covers OSX but not Windows (I know, I'm not asking much! ;) )

[How to send MIDI or OSC signals to a Mac application from my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201791/how-to-send-midi-or-osc-signals-to-a-mac-application-from-my-ios-application)

Cheers,

John.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you'll have to publish the service yourself. NSNetService and NSNetServiceBrowser are the classes you need. Check out the [companion guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html). I found [this article](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxviii-bonjour-and-how-do-you-do) on Cocoa for Scientists particularly helpful in getting started. Both have some decent code samples. The [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) is useful for testing.

The [list of bonjour service types](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServiceTypes.html) already has

> apple-midi

and

> imidi

But I think it's best to make up your own application-specific type name unless your app is plug-compatible with one of these services.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That is most helpful and I think I have enough info to be going on with now :)